# How to determine the values of parameters controlling the game objects?

Tags: unity, component-based

I am a C# developer and now trying to change to my dream field: Game Development.

I am new to Game Development and currently self learning Unity3D.

To me Unity is component based tools and we can set different parameters to control the behavior of the game object.

---

There's a question which kept me wonder for a long time:

**Is there any "scientific" method to determine the value of the parameters of the component other than trial & error (brute force)?**

Like when I watch some tutorials, the tutors normally will just tell you "change this value to x, change that to y" without tell you why is it so.

I just want to know how industry game developers set the value, is there a common standard, etc.

Comment: This will obviously depend on what *kind* of parameter you're setting. If I'm setting a force or velocity parameter, then I'll often be able to work out the right value from a clear definition of the desired behaviour and some basic equations of motion in Newtonian physics. If I'm setting the drop rate of an item from a chest, I'll more likely employ probability theory and a desired balancing curve. If I'm tuning enemy spawns, I'll be comparing against my desired difficulty curve and playtest data. So without these details, your question is too broad. Try asking about a specific tuning problem

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks! Indeed solely your comment is what I want to know as a brief big picture of the whole. Of course I can imagine there is different specific way to tune parameters regarding different scenarios, what I want to know is a list of those methods (and corresponding scenario if possible) so that I can do my own research... Indeed "Basic Newtonian Physics Equations", "Probability theory & balancing curve", "difficulty curve" etc. could be an answer to my OP... I am thinking how to rephrase my question, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

For all kinds of game developent you need to know things like vectors, triginometry and other types of math. You can calculate everyting from how to animate how gravity effect an object, to how each particle in an exploding fireworks, should behave when they explode. All this is mathematically calculating code. The x and y, is coordinates, but you have to start with understanding that in a computer we do not use degrees but radian, and the grades go the other way than you learned in school. It goes with the clock, so when you go from 0 to 20 to 45 degrees, you go down and left, and not up. There are many thins you need to start to learn if you want to do game development. Coding Math on Youtube.com is the beste intro tutorial i know. I teaches you everything in javascript, but you should not care about the language he is using, it is just to make it easy to learn that he is using javacript, because it is running in a browser. Good luck :-)